# How do I update the HTML when a button is clicked (change image when button is clicked)?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to update the HTML when a button is clicked.

I have tried to solve this issue for a few hours now and I don't know if I'm stupid, but the images are not changing.

```js
const slider = document.querySelector(".slider")

const btn = document.querySelector(".next")
const btn2 = document.querySelector(".previous")
const images = ['car.jpg', `left.jpg`]
window.addEventListener("load", iniliatizeSlider())

function iniliatizeSlider(){
    var x = 0
    cars = ''
    cars += `<div class="slide">
                <img src="${images[x]}" alt"client">
                <br><br>
             </div>`
    slider.innerHTML = cars;
}


btn.addEventListener("click", consoleMsg)
btn2.addEventListener("click", consoleMsg2)
function consoleMsg(){
    x=1
}
function consoleMsg2(){
    x=0
}
```

```html
    <section id="slider-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="subcontainer">
          <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <h2>client showcase</h2>
            <br />
            <div class="slider"></div>
            <div id="controls">
              <button class="previous">
                <img src="left.jpg" alt="previous client" />
              </button>
              <button class="next">
                <img src="right.jpg" alt="next client" />
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I was expecting the image to change when the button was clicked, but the image stayed the same, but the value of x changed.

Comment: "Nothing is working" is not a good description of a problem. what exactly is not working? What do you expect? What is happening instead?

Comment: A couple of things... With `.addEventListener()`, you pass a reference to the callback function, not invoke the function, so the line should be: `window.addEventListener("load", iniliatizeSlider)` <-- no () after the function name. Also, you don't need to replace the HTML on the page to update the image, you only need to update the image's `src` property.

Comment: @cloned the thing I'm trying to achieve is to change the image when the button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initialize function is running once, when the page loads and at that point you are setting the image source to 0 and you never change it after that. You need to adjust the image source within the functions that react to button clicks. Now you do update `x` in those functions but nothing is ever done with `x` after that point.

A couple of other things... With `.addEventListener()`, you pass a reference to the callback function, not invoke the function, so the line should be: `window.addEventListener("load", iniliatizeSlider)` <-- no () after the function name.

Also, you don't need to replace the HTML on the page to update the image, you only need to update the image's `src` property.

See comments below:

```js
// Get a reference to an existing image element.
// No need to recreate the <img> element.
const img = document.querySelector(".slider img");

const next = document.querySelector(".next");
const prev = document.querySelector(".previous");
const images = ["https://cache.mrporter.com/content/images/cms/ycm/resource/blob/1252204/68e7f03297f41cb3ce41f15ec478f70f/image-data.jpg/w1500_q80.jpg", "https://play-lh.googleusercontent.com/VC7rta8PIK3MqmQG5c-F5CNJQ6cCv6Eb-kyBoUcQ2xj83dZVhn7YCj_GIWW8y7TnAMjU=w240-h480-rw"];

let currentIndex = 0; // Keeps track of which image is shown

next.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Check to see if we're at the end of the array
  if(currentIndex === images.length-1){
    currentIndex = 0; // Reset index
  } else {
      currentIndex++; // increase the index
  }
  img.src = images[currentIndex]; // Just update the existing image's source
});

prev.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // Check to see if we're at the beginning of the array
  if(currentIndex === 0){
    currentIndex = images.length-1; // Reset index
  } else {
    currentIndex--; // decrease the index
  }
  img.src = images[currentIndex]; // Just update the existing image's source
});
```

```css
img { width:50px; }
```

```html
<section id="slider-section">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="subcontainer">
          <div class="slider-wrapper">
            <h2>client showcase</h2>
            <br >
            <div class="slider">
              <!-- Here, we just put a static image element with the first image we want to see. -->
              <img src="https://cache.mrporter.com/content/images/cms/ycm/resource/blob/1252204/68e7f03297f41cb3ce41f15ec478f70f/image-data.jpg/w1500_q80.jpg">
            </div>
            <div id="controls">
              <button class="previous">
                <img src="left.jpg" alt="previous client">
              </button>
              <button class="next">
                <img src="right.jpg" alt="next client">
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score -2):

Call the function initializeSlider() on click of `btn` instead of consoleMsg().

Comment: As is, x would always stay 0 -> No change would occur.

Comment: thank you for your answer but it did not help I'm trying to change the image when one of the buttons is clicked and in the future, I want to make it a slider or carousel

Comment: Elaborate and use a better example by adding a working code snippet.